# Why use Static Inner Class in Android Settings SettingsActivity

Tags: java, android

when i read Settings source code in Android,I found this code

```
public class Settings extends SettingsActivity {
    /*
    * Settings subclasses for launching independently.
    */
    public static class BluetoothSettingsActivity extends SettingsActivity { /* empty */ }
    public static class WirelessSettingsActivity extends SettingsActivity { /* empty */ }
    public static class SimSettingsActivity extends SettingsActivity { /* empty */ }
    public static class TetherSettingsActivity extends SettingsActivity { /* empty */ }
    ...
}
```

could any one tell me What are the benefits of doing so? could we use SettingsActivity directly？

Answer (score 0):

For the most part it's just a namespacing technique. These examples are identical in functionality, they just have different usages for `B`.

```
public class A { // class A
    public static class B { // class A.B

    }
}
```

---

```
public class A { // class A

}

public class B { // class B

}
```

A `public static` inner class acts exactly the same as a class that isn't nested. You just have to give the outer class first to access the inner class, such as doing:

```
new Settings.BluetoothSettingsActivity()
```

If `static` wasn't specified though, there would be a big difference. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70324/5743988).